# Python Matplotlib Radial labels on the point and on the unit circle with rotation

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do you put labels on points `x` extending outward from the location of the point `x` in the direction of `x`? As an extension, how would you place a label on the unit circle where the angle is the same as that of `x` (again the label text must be rotated to have the same direction as `x`, extending outward)? Thanks.

`ax.text` with `rotation` can help resolve the orientation of the label but the position of the text relative to the point has different definition according to the rotation. i.e. for some rotations the text extends outwards while for others it extends inwards and for some it is somewhere in between.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How is your data structured? Are you using a pandas dataframe, numpy array, or other? Can you give us an example dataset or code that produces a sample dataset? What kind of code have you tried so far?

Comment: A point `x` has no direction. Also *"for some rotations the text extends outwards while for others it extends inwards"* is really not clear. If you want people to help you, consider spending a little more effort into explaining the problem you need help with. Consider using pictures and code to explain the issue in detail.

Comment: 1 is a directed positive, -1 is directed negative, (1,sqrt(3)) is directed 60 degrees north of east etc. inwards as in towards the origin, outwards as in towards the infinite norm.